# I want my the following code to perform a loop multiple times taking the new values?

Tags: python, loops, iteration

I have a code in python. i want it to run multiple times like in a loop. lets say 20 times. What syntax would I use?

So for the following code, I want it to go into loop and slope the functions multiple times and give me the results .

```
p1g = float(input("Player 1 Utility for green"))
p2r = float(input("Player 2 ulitity for red"))
p1r = float(input("Player 1 utility for red"))
p2g = float(input("Player 2 utility for green"))
d1 = float(input("Player 1 Disagreement point"))
d2 = float (input("Player 2 Disagreement point"))
"""Returns the slope and intercept of the payoff/utilities"""
i = 1
while i < 20:
 m = (p2g-p2r)/(p1r-p1g)
 c = p2r - ((p2g-p2r)/(p1r-p1g))* p1g
 nash_bargaining_x = -(p2r -d2 - m*p1g - m*d1)/2*m
 nash_bargaining_y = -(p2r -d2 - m*p1g - m*d1) + c # where c = p1g-p2r * ((p2g-p2r)/(p1r-p1g)
 solution = [nash_bargaining_x,nash_bargaining_y]
 print (solution)
 if abs(p1g-nash_bargaining_x) > abs(p1r-nash_bargaining_x):
     solution = "P1 has Red"
 else:
    solution = "P2 has red"
 print(solution)
 if solution in ["P1 has red"]:
  p1r = p1r + 25 and p1g = p1r - 20 and p2g = p2g - 15 and p2r = p2g + 35
 else:
  p1r = p1g + 25 and p1g = p1g -25 and p2g = p2r - 20 and p2r = p2r + 25
```

syntax error : cant assign to operator

Comment: `a = b and c = d` - what do you think this is supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

> `p1r = p1r + 25 and p1g = p1r - 20 and p2g = p2g - 15 and p2r = p2g + 35`

You likely meant

```
if solution == "P1 has red":
  p1r = p1r + 25
  p1g = p1r - 20
  p2g = p2g - 15
  p2r = p2g + 35
```

(`and`was the operator in the error message; it is used to compute boolean expressions, not to join a sequence of assignment operators.)

Comment: thank you. it did run but now the loop is not ending. this is my first time using a loop so i dont know what is going on. The loop is going on and on and not stopping for 20th time

Comment: to have the loop stop you need to add the statement ```i += 1``` at the end of the loop. You are currently looping while ```i<20``` but ```i``` never changes its value from 0

Comment: I did do that but it is still running infinitely.

Comment: You never `break` and apparently never increase (or otherwise use) the value of `i`, so `i < 20` always holds true. If you just want 20 runs, you can do `for _ in range(20): ...` instead.

Comment: Thank you. yes it did work for 20 times but now the issue is that IT is not updating the values of p1r or p2g as it runs the program. It just givesme same result for 20 times.